# Basic Bootstrap drop-down menu - can't get it to work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I seem to be unable to get a basic Bootstrap drop-down menu to work.

I didn't overwrite any of the CSS. I did include a small JS for smooth scrolling links which could be messing with it?

CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

HTML

```
<!-- Test dropdown -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- End test dropdown -->
```

JS

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {
      if (this.hash !== "") {
        event.preventDefault();
        var hash = this.hash;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function(){
          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bootstrap drop-down also needs JavaScript to work. No JS = no drop-down.

Here you go (click "run code snippet" below to see it working):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Test dropdown -->
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- End test dropdown -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").on('click', function(event) {
            if (this.hash !== "") {
                event.preventDefault();
                var hash = this.hash;
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 800, function(){
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```